# How to use hostinger domain with github pages

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I have a website hosted on github pages and I bought a domain name from hostinger. I am adding A records and CNAME. But the website is going to "parked domain name on hostinger" instead of my github page. Afaik I am doing everything correctly and adding the correct IPs in the A records.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try with CNAM record.
this is what this doc says
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: Welcome to SO Suraj. The OP said they had already added a CNAME record.

Answer (score 0):

Create two AAAA DNS adress and put the following ipv6 adresses:
2606:50c0:8000::153 and
2606:50c0:8000::154